# What is the best way to authenticate Express api?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, passport.js

I use Angular 4 as a front end and MongoDB for database. I used Express to create API. Now I need to authenticate every API except login and register to prevent unauthorized users to hit API.

I am new to this kind of authentication and I found lot of methods available such as passport.js, jwt etc. I am very confused to choose the best method for authenticating. So please give some inputs to choose the best.

Note: The application is not related to financial projects. So it doesn't require high level of safety.

Comment: If it doesn't require high level of safety, why do you care which one is the best? Just pick whatever you want.

Comment: What do you care about?  How do you define "best"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to implement [Json Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/)

For NodeJS, there is a npm Package available called [nJwt](https://github.com/jwtk/njwt). You can install it with npm.

Usage example (shortened):

```
var njwt = require('njwt');
if (loginSuccessful) {
    var payload = {
                        iss: 'your_domain_name',
                        iat: Math.round((Date.now() / 1000)),
                        // Set expiration date to now +7200 seconds
                        exp: Math.round((Date.now() / 1000)) + 7200,
                        username: username,
                        ip: ip
                }
   var token = njwt.create(payload,your_super_secret_key,'HS512').compact());
} else {
// Login not successful, don't give key
}
```

You can send the token to the user, and then they use it with every request (for example).

With this configuration the token will be valid for 7200 seconds, or 2 hours.